# SAS data manipulation from CSV file, merging rows

Tags: csv, merge, sas

I have data in a csv file.  The first row of the file has the time point, the second row has symptoms.  Each time point is a merged cell for several symptoms. Something like:

```
ID     Timepoint 1                     Timepoint2
       Symptom 1   Symptom 2  Symptom 3 Symptom 1   Symptom 2  Symptom 3 

1         0            1         1         2           1         2
```

but I have many more rows and columns

I would like to get a SAS data set like this

```
ID   Timepoint     Symptom 1   Symptom 2  Symptom 3
1         1            0           1        1
1         2            2           1        2
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the data step to read the data into that structure.

```
data symptom;
   infile cards firstobs=4;
   input id @;
   do timepoint=1,2;
      input symptom1-symptom3 @;
      output;
      end;
   cards;
ID     Timepoint 1                     Timepoint2
       Symptom 1   Symptom 2  Symptom 3 Symptom 1   Symptom 2  Symptom 3 

1         0            1         1         2           1         2
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Comment: Thanks.  That works great with CARDS but when I try to do that from the CSV file, I get a mess.  e.g.  PROC IMPORT OUT= WORK.symptoms 
            DATAFILE= "C:\personal\Consults\TA Sciences\Laser study\Symptoms.csv" 
            DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
     GETNAMES=YES;
     DATAROW=2; 
RUN;   gives me a lot of variables named VAR2 VAR3 etc.  If I change it to datarow = 3 I get a similar mess.

Comment: Sorry about the messy format.  Comments here are hard to edit.

Comment: Just replace INFILE CARDS with the path to your CSV.  No PROC IMPORT involved.